Prove for all $x\in \mathbb R$ that $1-\tan^2(f(x)) = 2x\tan(f(x))$ where $f(x)=\arctan(\sqrt{x^2+1}-x)$.
I was doing the following exercise: prove for all $x\in \mathbb R$ that $1-\tan^2(f(x)) = 2x\tan(f(x))$ where $f(x)=\arctan(\sqrt{x^2+1}-x)$. The previous question was about proving that $0<f(x)<\frac{\pi}2$ which is easy. When doing the question I got $1-\tan^2(f(x))=-2x\tan(f(x))$ which is false apparently (negative of the book's answer). The book's proof. I'm sorry if I didn't write this question very good as it is my first time using stackexchange.
My proof:
$$\begin{align}1-\tan^2(f(x)) &= 1-\left(\sqrt{1+x^2}-x\right)^2\\ &=1-\left(1+x^2-2x\sqrt{x^2+1}+x^2\right)\\ &=-2x^2+2x\sqrt{x^2+1}\\&=-2x\left(x-\sqrt{1+x^2}\right)\\&=-2x\tan(f(x))\end{align}$$

Hi welcome to Stack Exchange! This is a perfectly legitimate question, but it will be easier to read if you write it using MathJax - have a read on the Meta page for more information on this, but it works analogously to Latex!

You assume $\tan(f(x))=x-\sqrt{1+x^2}$ on the last line which is not quite equivalent to $f(x)=\arctan(\sqrt{x^2+1}-x)$

Here's an alternate way, assume $x$ to be $\cot u$,
$$\sqrt{1+u^2}-u=\frac{1-\cos u}{\sin u}=\tan \frac u2$$
Indicating that $f(x)=\frac u2$, and
$$1-\tan^2 \bigg(\frac u2\bigg)=\\\tan\bigg(\frac u2\bigg)\bigg\{\cot\bigg(\frac u2\bigg) -\tan\bigg(\frac u2\bigg)\bigg\}\\
=2\cot u\tan\bigg(\frac u2\bigg) \\
\implies 1-\tan^2(f(x))=2x\tan(f(x))$$
